# Why does my Floating Action Button only work when it is above the listview?

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button, android-elevation

While trying to create a UI, I noticed that my `FloatingActionButton` when having the same elevation as the `ListView` and inside of the `ListView` boundaries, the button won't work. However, when I increase the elevation of the `FloatingActionButton` to be above the `ListView` everything works fine.

Does the FAB, when the elevation increases, get render on a different surfaces so that it is able to be reach? Or is there other mechanism that knows that the button is situated above the `ListView` so when the button is clicked, the conflicting boundaries between the `ListView` and the FAB is solve?

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: I don't think I need to add any code. You can just go test it for yourself by adding a listview and a button having the button overlapped with  the listview. Remove the elevation of both and you have the situation I describe above.

Comment: the order of your layout matters too. you try putting the FAB after your listview.